# How to bind FormArray retrieve by API?

Tags: angular, formarray, formgroups

Here's how I retrieve data from API and bind on FormGroup elements in angular:

```
this.api.GetRecipe(id).subscribe((data) => {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    nome: [data.nome, [Validators.required]],
    ingredienti: this.fb.group({
      acqua: [data.ingredienti.acqua, [Validators.required]]
    })
  });
});
```

but I don't know how to bind in case of array. Such as retrieve `farine` there (which is an array of objects):

```
this.api.GetRecipe(id).subscribe((data) => {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    nome: [data.nome, [Validators.required]],
    ingredienti: this.fb.group({
      acqua: [data.ingredienti.acqua, [Validators.required]],
      farine: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          quantita: [data.ingredienti.farine[x].quantita, [Validators.required]],
          forza: [data.ingredienti.farine[x].forza, [Validators.required]]
        })
      ])
    })
  });
});
```

of course `[x]` isn't anywhere. Where do I retrieve x on every iteration? Or what's the way to propagate data from API to each FormGroup? Lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to create array of formGroup

```
this.api.GetRecipe(id).subscribe((data) => {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    nome: [data.nome, [Validators.required]],
    ingredienti: this.fb.group({
      acqua: [data.ingredienti.acqua, [Validators.required]],
      farine: this.fb.array(
       data.ingredienti.farine.map(ingredient=>(
         this.fb.group({
          quantita: [ingredient.quantita, [Validators.required]],
          forza: [ingredient.forza, [Validators.required]]
        })))
      )
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: I've correct a typo. It seems to works with map. Nice. thanks